# pavucontrol shows Line-out as unplugged when Headphones are plugged in

Tags: audio, fedora, pulse-audio

I have my speakers plugged in to the Line Out jack. When I plug my headphones into the front headphone jack, the speakers are muted and sound is played in my headphones, as expected. However, when I open up `pavucontrol` and manually select to send sound to Line Out (which is listed as unplugged) it mutes the headphones (as expected) but does *NOT* play audio out the speakers.

I've tried many different permutations of `pactl` and `pacmd`, with `set-sink-port` and other commands, and every time, either nothing changes, or both the speakers and headphones are silent, as they are when I try to do it with `pavucontrol`.

**TL;DR;** I want to be able to switch between headphones and speakers while both are plugged in, but the speakers are ALWAYS silent when my headphones are plugged in.

I'm running up-to-date Fedora 23 with the KDE 5 desktop.

Comment: in `alsamixer`  set  auto-mute to enabled  ---problem solved

Comment: @linuxdev2013 I sure don't see any auto-mute option in alsamixer....

Answer (score 11):

1. Open up alsamixer. Then press **F6** to select your sound card, most likely ending with PCH.
2. Scroll right till you find the **Auto-Mute** option.
3. Press up or down arrow to disable it. Press Esc to quit alsamixer. 
   [image: alsamixer settings]

Use the following script to automate it.

```
#!/bin/sh

NAME=$(basename -- "$0")

command -v amixer >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "amixer not installed"; exit 1; }
command -v pacmd >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "pacmd not installed"; exit 1; }

amixer -c1 sset "Auto-Mute Mode" Disabled > /dev/null

if [ -z $1 ]; then
  echo -e "Usage:\nFront Speakers\t: $NAME 0\t\nHeadphones\t: $NAME 1\nBoth Speakers\t: $NAME 2"
  exit 1
elif [ $1 -eq 0 ] 2> /dev/null; then
  pacmd set-sink-port 1 analog-output-lineout
  amixer -c1 set Headphone 0% > /dev/null
  amixer -c1 set Front 100% > /dev/null
elif [ $1 -eq 1 ] 2> /dev/null; then
  pacmd set-sink-port 1 analog-output-headphones
  amixer -c1 set Front 0% > /dev/null
  amixer -c1 set Headphone 100% > /dev/null
elif [ $1 -eq 2 ] 2> /dev/null; then
  pacmd set-sink-port 1 analog-output-headphones
  amixer -c1 set Front 100% > /dev/null
  amixer -c1 set Headphone 100% > /dev/null
else
  echo -e "Invalid argument"
  exit 1
fi
```

This assumes that the card you are using is numbered 1. Also, it assumes that your PulseAudio ports are named **analog-output-lineout** and **analog-output-headphones**.
Save it as something like **speakers.sh** and chmod to set execute bit.

Run `speakers.sh 1` for Headphones and `speakers.sh 0` for Speakers.

Comment: Wait...it doesn't quite work. Now audio plays out both, when headphones are chosen. i.e. it always plays out of speakers regardless of whether Line Out or Headphones are selected.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe You could always mute the speakers through alsamixer.

Comment: Yes I could, but I don't want to have so many steps needed...I wish I could just quickly and easily toggle between two outputs!

Comment: check main post for automation script

Comment: Thank you for answer , it saves me from some headaches .